# SELECT de múltiples tablas

Tags: sql, join

Buenas, estoy tratando de hacer una `SELECT`de múltiples tablas en las que quiero seleccionar la fecha de cada registro según un usuario introducido, el código que tengo por ahora es:

```
SELECT Acept_Hora, Marc_Fec, Cont_Mod, Emp_Mod, Dir_Mod, Fac_Fech, 
Fol_Date, Prod_Fec, Red_Mod, Punc_Date, Usu_Fecha_Reg, Usu_Fec_Mod 
FROM anunciosaceptados 
INNER JOIN anunciosmarcados ON anunciosaceptados.Acept_Usu = 
anunciosmarcados.Marc_Usu
INNER JOIN contacto ON anunciosaceptados.Acept_Usu = contacto.Con_Usu
INNER JOIN datos_empresa ON anunciosaceptados.Acept_Usu = datos_empresa.Emp_Usu
INNER JOIN direcciones ON anunciosaceptados.Acept_Usu = direcciones.Dir_Usu
INNER JOIN facturas ON anunciosaceptados.Acept_Usu = facturas.Fact_Vend_Usu
INNER JOIN followers ON anunciosaceptados.Acept_Usu = followers.Fol_User
INNER JOIN productos ON anunciosaceptados.Acept_Usu = productos.Prod_Usu
INNER JOIN redes_sociales ON anunciosaceptados.Acept_Usu = redes_sociales.Red_Usu
INNER JOIN user_punctuation ON anunciosaceptados.Acept_Usu = user_punctuation.Punc_Voter
INNER JOIN usu_datos ON anunciosaceptados.Acept_Usu = usu_datos.Usu_Usu
```

Si por ejemplo el usuario fuese Pepe, que de devolviera todas las fechas registradas dónde el usuario fuese Pepe. El caso es que me muestra los resultados pero con muchísimos campos repetidos. La primera columna puede tener varias fechas ya que el usuario puede haber puntuado más de una vez algún producto, pero la segunda y la tercera sólo puede haber una fecha ya que indica la última modificación de los datos de la empresa y de contacto. Aún así me los muestra tantas veces como fechas de puntuación hay, espero explicarme bién.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
Cómo puedo solucionar mi problema?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0):

Necesitas usar las clausulas `LIMIT` y `ORDER BY`, primero ordenarías los resultados de izquierda a derecha por columnas asegurando que siempre tendrás el primer registro de cada columna en la fila 1, luego limítas todos los resultados; solo quieres 1 registro.

Considera el siguiente query, el resultado es un solo registro:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... 
ORDER BY Acept_Hora, Marc_Fec, Cont_Mod, Emp_Mod, Dir_Mod, Fac_Fech, Fol_Date, Prod_Fec, Red_Mod, Punc_Date, Usu_Fecha_Reg, Usu_Fec_Mod 
LIMIT 1;
```

Pero si lo que quieres es un registro por un criterio en específico pero muchos en el resultado del query entonces necesitas usar `GROUP BY`; para implmentarlo en tu situación se requiere más información pero tendrías algo así al final:

```
SELECT ...
GROUP BY producto
ORDER BY Acept_Hora;
```

Aquí los datos se agruparían por producto, ordenados por Acept_Hora. En otras palabras, el primer registro de cada producto ordenado por Acept_Hora.